# Calculate the following limit.

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm trying to find the following limit.
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x2^x}{(2+\epsilon)^x}$$
$\epsilon$ is a positive contsant value. While trying to solve it like $$\lim_{x \to \infty} x\left(\frac{2}{2+\epsilon}\right)^x$$ I cross a $\infty \cdot 0$ ambiguity and I don't know how to solve it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have $\frac{x}{a^x}$, where $a>1$.

Comment: Usually when you have $\infty\times 0$ you can rewrite it as $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$

Answer (score 0):

We have:
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x2^x}{(2+\epsilon)^x}$$
Clearly, it's a $[0\cdot +\infty]$ indefinite form. We can rewrite as follows:
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x2^x}{(2+\epsilon)^x}=\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{x}{\left(\frac{2+\epsilon}{2}\right)^x}=\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{x}{\underbrace{\left({1+\frac{\epsilon}{2}}\right)^x}_{>1}}=0$$
Your limit is $0$ by the hierarchy of infinity.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply [L'Hopital's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) in such situations, because

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} x =\lim_{x \to \infty} (\frac{2+\varepsilon}{2})^x=\infty$$
So we have
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x2^x}{(2+\epsilon)^x}=\\\text {rearange the terms}\\=\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{x}{(\frac{2+\varepsilon}{2})^x}=\\
\text {apply L'Hopital Rule}\\=\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{1}{(\frac{2+\varepsilon}{2})^x\ln(\frac{2+\varepsilon}{2})}=\\
\text {calculate the limit of the fraction}\\=0$$